# Nested query with rank() in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a SQL query like this one:

```
select t1_id, t2_id, n, v, rank
from
  (
   select t3.t1_id, t3.t2_id, t1.n, t2.v, rank() over (partition by t3.t1_id order by t3.c desc) as rank
   from t3 join t2 ON t3.t2_id = t2.id join t1 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
   where t1.a='val' and t2.d id null
   order by t1.n, t2.v
  ) as ss
where rank>1
order by rank desc
limit 1
```

I am having trouble translating this to jOOQ, especially the `rank>1`part which causes a compile error. This is what I have so far:

```
SelectConditionStep query = jooq.select(T3.T1_ID, T3.T2_ID, T1.N, T2.V, rank().over(partitionBy(T3.T1_ID).orderBy(T3.C.desc())).as("rank"))
  .from(T3.join(T2).onKey().join(T1).onKey())
  .where(T1.A.eq('val')).and(T2.D.isNull());

jooq.select(query.field(T3.T1_ID), query.field(T3.T2_ID), query.field(T1.N), query.field(T2.V), query.field("rank"))
  .from(query)
  .where(query.field("rank").greaterThan(1))
  .orderBy(query.field("rank").desc())
  .limit(1)
  .fetch();
```

The only way I can get it to work is by using `where("rank>1")`

What is the correct way to translate the query in a type-safe manner?

Comment: What compilation error are you getting? This compiles just fine for me (apart from raw type usage warnings...)

Comment: This is the error (in IntelliJ): Cannot resolve method greaterThan(int)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not getting this error in IntelliJ (Ultimate) 14.0.2... I'm using jdk 1.8.0_40-ea-b21. What version(s) are you using?